# How to start an interactive shell in a container that continuously exits?

Tags: docker

I started a container instance using a postgres image. Whilst the container was running I connected to it using

`docker exec -it postgres-13.1 bash`

From here I edited the `postgresql.conf` and introduced a typo such that attempting to restart the container immediately exits and the logs show

```
FATAL:  configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors
```

It isn't possible to excute a bash script using `docker exec -it postgres-13.1 bash` because this only applies to a running container.

What command can I issue to start the container and drop directly into a bash shell instead of attempting to start the database server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker cp` can copy files into (or out) a stopped container.
This should be sufficient to repair the file and restart the container.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Mentioned, `docker cp` command works for your case
Create a file (say correct-postgresql.conf ) with configuration in your machine and do the following and then you can start your container and it works fine.

```
docker cp correct-postgresql.conf <containerId>:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding good solution by Chris, the more stable solution is to mount `postgresql.conf` file onto your host machine. Doing so, you'll be able to change your postgre configurations without accessing to running container. You also won't need to docker cp conf file into the container. you can mount .conf file as below
`docker run -v /home/<your-user>:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf ....`
But if you've created the container in prior, you now should change the container configurations via `/var/lib/docker/containers/<postgre-container-long-hashed-ID>/hostconfig.json` file:

```
1. docker stop <postgre-container>
2. change /var/lib/docker/containers/<postgre-container-long-hashed-ID>/hostconfig.json file as formal notation for mounting a filesystem
3. save changes to hostconfig.json file
4. sudo systemctl start docker.service
5. docker start <postgre-container>
```